# Java: permute data in a list

Tags: java, list, permutation

I have a list of elements, **every element has a map**, with Integer key and any Object value, doesn't matter. Then for every element in my list i want to make the permutation in the elements map.

```
<Map<Integer,Object> myMap= {[0,null] [1,A]; [2,B]; [3,C]; [4,D]};
```

After some operations I have a map of the permutation like:

```
Map<Integer,Integer> changes = {1=2, 2=3, 3=4, 4=1}
```

So I want to rearange my list to have

```
 Map<Integer,Object> myMap = {[0,null] [1,B]; [2,C]; [3,D]; [4,A]};
```

Can it be done worgout using an other list where I save the myList's data, then set the my List-s item depending on permutation?

I can do it by using a helper list like:

```
Map<Integer,Object> helperMap= {[0,null] [1,A]; [2,B]; [3,C]; [4,D]};
```

then

```
changes.forEach((key,value) ->{
    myList.set(key,helperList.get(value));
}
```

I was thinking about to use just one variable to store one element but I could not manage to do it, and I don't really have any better idea.
Can you suggest me a better idea than this if there exists.

Note:  I know there is a Collections.rotate method, that does similar thing, but the elements in my list are quite complex and I want to reorder them by their ids.
After every reordering the numbering system(or the elements ids) wont change just the data itself, and every time the numbering is in ascending order from 1 to elements.size()-1.

Edit: inverted the values in a list to represent better the data that I have.

Edit2 : list replaced to map, so in a list for every map I want to do this.

Comment: Can you turn the items into a number representing where they are in the list, so if you sort them by this number they would be in order, if so you can do this `items.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(<SOME CODE>))` instead of sorting manually?

Comment: Doesn't this code gives you syntax error ?

Comment: @jrtapsell in the background is  complex structure, so I cannot use just `Collections.sort` using a custom comparator. @Jayesh of course it doesn't compiles, that is just a mockup to show what I want.

Comment: Couldn't you use comparingInt on the second numbers, to sort the list by the second with the items joined to the position pairs

Comment: What is the datastructure of the element that is present in your list

Comment: It is a `Map<Integer, Object>`so I want to reorder the data using its key.

Comment: Can the maps be pairs instead, making the starting list `List<Pair<Integer, Object>>`, or do they need to hold multiple pairs of values?

Comment: Maybe I was wrong I am updating the questin in a minute

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import javafx.util.Pair;

public class T2 {

  public static void main(final String... args) {

    Map<Integer, Object> first = new HashMap<>();
    first.put(0, null);

    List<Map<Integer, Object>> myList = List.of(
        first,
        Map.of(1,"A"),
        Map.of(2,"B"),
        Map.of(3,"C"),
        Map.of(4,"D"));

    Map<Integer,Integer> changes = Map.of(0,0,1,2, 2,3, 3,4, 4,1);

    Map<Integer,Integer> flipped = changes.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getValue, Map.Entry::getKey));

    System.out.println(IntStream.range(0, myList.size())
        .mapToObj(p -> new Pair<>(myList.get(p), flipped.get(p)))
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(p -> p.getValue()))
        .map(p -> p.getKey())
        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
  }
}
```

It outputs this:

`[{0=null}, {2=B}, {3=C}, {4=D}, {1=A}]`

- First it flips the swap map, so {x=y} means x becomes y
- Then it pairs the objects with their new index
- It then sorts by the new index
- Finally it removes the indexes, leaving only the objects in place

*The first bit is needed because Java 9 Map.of does not support null values, the code other than the Map.of and List.of uses for making the data structures is all Java 8 compatible*

Comment: Update completed

Comment: Ah so you are using Java9  I was wondering what are `List.of` and `Map.of`because I have never seen them. I think this is not the solution for me, because I have to permute values in a map. I think I was wrong in the question.

Comment: Allocating a second map would probably be a lot easier, and as the objects are just being reordered you wouldn't need to reallocate them, so the memory use increase of 2 maps might be small enough that it is better than the more complicated code.

Comment: Okay then maybe I will use the helper map solution.